# Limit scroll wheel zoom level on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code that should limit the zooming within my map. The Zoom is limited when I manually click the zoom in and zoom out buttons (plus and minus) of the map controls. This is somehow not happening when I'm using a scroll-wheel to zoom. How can I limit the zoom level that my scroll-wheel is applying? I don't want to deactivate the zoom via scroll-wheel.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 52.520008, lng: 13.404954},
    });

    var old_zoom_level = 12;
    map.data.loadGeoJson('data/1000_berlin_buildings.json');
    //map.data.loadGeoJson('google.json');

    map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
    map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseInToRegion);
    map.data.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutOfRegion);

    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function(){
        //console.log("bounds changed");
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        // if (map.getZoom() < 9) map.setZoom(9);
        var new_zoom_level = map.getZoom();
        console.log("zoom Changed from "+ old_zoom_level +" to "+new_zoom_level);

        if (new_zoom_level < __min_zoom_level) {
            new_zoom_level = __min_zoom_level;
            map.setZoom(__min_zoom_level);
        }
        if (new_zoom_level > __max_zoom_level) {
            new_zoom_level = __max_zoom_level;
            map.setZoom(__max_zoom_level);
        }
        old_zoom_level = new_zoom_level;
    });

}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work.

Comment: @MrUpsidown can you explain what is not working for you? I see that I had the map.setZoom() commented, but I tested it with those  lines uncommented. I edited the example code

Comment: You are required to post the minimal code to reproduce the problem as well as a clear problem statement and the desired behavior. `__min_zoom_level` etc. are not defined. So I can't run your code as it is.

Comment: That said the behavior when doing the above is a bit strange... If you use `bounds_changed` event, it seems to work. But anyway that's not really how you should do it IMO. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in a much easier way, by using the map `minZoom` and `maxZoom` properties.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 52.520008, lng: 13.404954},
    minZoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 14
});
```

If you need these values to change at any point, simply use the map `setOptions()` method:

```
map.setOptions({
  minZoom: 8,
  maxZoom: 15
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 52.520008,
      lng: 13.404954
    },
    minZoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 14,
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {

    map.setOptions({
      minZoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 15
    });
  })
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<button id="btn">Change limits to min: 5 and max: 15</button>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```